# Spaces aren't being removed from first variable

Tags: linux, bash, awk, eval

This script is supposed to remove leading and trailing spaces from variables in a file, and insert them into an SQL statement. This is working for every variable except for the first one. It will not remove trailing spaces from the user ID. I have attached the sample file and code being used to gather the variable data.

Sample File:

```
"User ID"|First|Last|Password|"E-Mail Address"|CreateDate|RequestDate|Requestor|Title|"Site Location"|"Client Name"|"Requestor Email"|Roles|Tasks|"Correspondance Packages"
"A145078 "|"James "|Joyce|" DO NOT USE"|jjames@job.com|" 2015/06/22 16:30:00"|"2015/06/20 17:00:00"|"John Edwards"|CSR|Aetna|Aetna|bavolt@aetna.com|"CTM Data Analyst, Medical Appeals Status/Status Reasons, RCA Status and Status Reasons, Grievance Status/Status Reasons, CTM Status/Status Reasons"||
```

Output Being Produced (see space after user_id:

```
INSERT INTO users(user_id, first, last, password, email, createdate, requestdate, requestby)VALUES('A145078 ','James','Joyce','DO NOT USE','jjames@job.com','2015/06/22 16:30:00','2015/06/20 17:00:00','John Edwards');
```

Code Utilized:

```
    #!/bin/bash
> user_adds.sql

while IFS="|" read -r uid first last password email createdate requestdate requestor title site client requestemail roles tasks packages; do
   #printf '%s %s\n' "$uid" "$first" "$roles"
   uid=$(echo "$uid" | sed 's/\"//g' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed 's/[ \t]*$//')
   first=$(echo "$first" | sed 's/\"//g' | sed "s/'/ /g" | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//')
   last=$(echo "$last" | sed 's/\"//g' | sed "s/'/ /g" | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//')
   echo $uid - "$uid"
   echo $roles

   echo "INSERT INTO users(user_id, first, last, password, email, createdate, requestdate, requestby)VALUES('$uid','$first','$last','DO NOT USE','$email','$createdate','$requestdate','$requestor');" >> user_adds.sql

   #echo "INSERT INTO user_demographics(user_id, title, site_location, comment, client_name, requester_email,last_password_date_changed)select id,'$title','$site_location','$title','$client','$request_email',NULL from users where user_id in('$user_id');" >> demo_adds.sql


done < 'new_users.csv'
```

Comment: This is a horrible approach to this problem. Using something like the solutions in [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) are better (for reasonbly sized files). As would be doing more of the trimming/etc. in awk or at least *without* using `eval` on arbitrary data.

Comment: Quick test on just that example line doesn't reproduce this problem here. What does `set -x` say about the operations on that first line?

Comment: Some of your input values are quoted.  awk treats quote as a valid char so  it won't trim the contents.

Comment: Then why are the other fields with " being trimmed properly? Like first name "James"?

Comment: Holy crap, throw that shell monster away before it invades Tokyo (or wipes out your home filesystem, whichever comes first)! The UNIX shell is an environment from which to call tools and the UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk so just write a brief, simple awk script to do the job. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins if it's not obvious how to do that.

Comment: I've updated my script and it's still not deleting the space at the end of the user id.

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to remove all spaces (beginning, middle, end). If this is what you need then you can simply replace `$uid` with `${uid// }`.

Comment: Can you run `cat -vET new_users.csv` and verify that the space you are seeing is indeed a space or tab. Better yet, find a hex editor and look at the file. Space is `0x20` in hex.

Comment: Interesting, it actually outputs "-BM- " at the end of it. What's that?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk        
BEGIN{ FS="[[:space:]\"]*[|][[:space:]\"]*" }
NR>1 {
    gsub(/^[[:space:]"]+|[[:space:]"]+$/,"")
    printf "INSERT INTO users(user_id, first, last, password, email, createdate, requestdate, requestby)VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
INSERT INTO users(user_id, first, last, password, email, createdate, requestdate, requestby)VALUES('A145078','James','Joyce','DO NOT USE','jjames@job.com','2015/06/22 16:30:00','2015/06/20 17:00:00','John Edwards');
```

Comment: I ran this, copy and pasted and it still has space at end of variable names.

Comment: @user3299633 - maybe it wasn't space after all. Maybe it was just non-printing character.

Comment: You are right. It's not a space. Any idea how to delete it?

Comment: Sure, just change every `[[:space:]]` in the above script to a bracket expression that includes whatever character class(es) you want treated like spaces, e.g. maybe `[^[:graph:]]` or `[[:space:][:cntrl:]]` or `[^[:alnum:][:punct:]]`. See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#table_002dchar_002dclasses and try combinations of the likely ones if you aren't sure.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the basic template you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

typeset -a  parts

cat <<'EOF'  |
"A145078 "|"James "|Joyce|" DO NOT USE"|jjames@job.com|" 2015/06/22 16:30:00"|"2015/06/20 17:00:00"|"John Edwards"|CSR|Aetna|Aetna|bavolt@aetna.com|"CTM Data Analyst, Medical Appeals Status/Status Reasons, RCA Status and Status Reasons, Grievance Status/Status Reasons, CTM Status/Status Reasons"||
EOF
while read line; do
    line=$( echo "${line}" | sed -e 's/" /"/g' -e 's/ "/"/g' -e 's/"//g')
    typeset -a parts=( ${line//|/ } )
    echo ${parts[@]}
    uid="${parts[0]}"
    first="${parts[1]}"
    last="${parts[2]}"
    echo "INSERT INTO users(user_id, first, last) VALUES ('$uid','$first','$last');"
done
```